# swipe to delete android

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I have a list view and it is populated from database.I want to delete a item ,after delete this item show the rest of all item in same activity and just changed ui.

Can anyone have better idea or can anyone help me.

Thanks and Regards 
Md Maidul Islam

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to just notify the data set adapter after delete record.

### Like

YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Below code set the data into Listview.

First Declare adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
lvlisting.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So when ever you delete record you just have to notify the adapter.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .Can you give some example.That might be help .

Comment: I catch all data from data base .So if you can give a example that can retrieve data from data base and delete a data.So data will delete data from database and refresh the UI in this activity. so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use handler it will help u

```
private Handler handler=new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeScreen.this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,array);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProfilelist.invalidate();              
    }

};
```

call the handler when u delete list item..

use this code call the handler

```
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .Can you give some example.

Comment: I catch all data from data base .So if you can give a example that can retrieve data from data base and delete a data.So data will delete data from database and refresh the UI in this activity. so please help me.